# How to mock scala readLine

Tags: scala, mocking, inputstream

I want to write a unit test for my main function where there is a  `readLine()` loop.

I have tried the following which is java based. I think `readLine()` might need `System.in` as `inputStream`. But it doesn't work. ScalaTest is blocked on the `readLine()` waiting for inputs.

```
"readLine" should "work" in {
  val in = new ByteArrayInputStream("abc".getBytes)
  System.setIn(in)
  readLine() === "tester"
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I am not clear on your question exactly. Are you looking for a better way of reading lines? io.Source.fromInputStream(...).getLines can read from input stream and is very easy to use or pass different streams.

Comment: What is `readLine` - is that the deprecated method in scala.Console, or scala.io.StdIn?  Or is that a function of your own making?  If so, can you post the source?

Comment: @soong, @rock-fall Sorry for the unclear question. What I want to do is an integration test and simulate user input to verify if my app's behavior is correct. Since there are some calls like `console.readLine()`, etc, I want to mock them, e.g. preprend some String in a `Inputbuffer` as the user input. Then, readLine() just reads the input from this `InputBuffer`.

Comment: for short, in the code snippet above, `readLine()` is expected to return "abc".

Comment: In addition. during the test, I don't want to and can't manually input some text.

Comment: I understand that part, but I think the problem you're having is with how readLine works.  If it is set up to use `System.in` *before* you call `setIn`, then it will already have a reference to the original input stream.  If you're using `scala.Console`, there are methods for setting the new input stream in that class that should solve your problem.  (Sadly, `scala.io.StdIn` relies on `scala.Console` but has no inherent methods for specify the input stream, though a subclass could do that).

Answer (score 5):

Maxim's solution actually didn't work for me (anymore?). So to help others who face the same issue:

```
val in = new ByteArrayInputStream(("abc").getBytes)

Console.withIn(in)  {
    assert(StdIn.readLine() === "abc")
}
```

Comment: Very handy. My sbt test loop ended up stuck requesting input with Maxim's solution.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to **Unit Test** it is to follow the ["ports and adapters"](http://www.dossier-andreas.net/software_architecture/ports_and_adapters.html) pattern.

So you should have an interface that is the 'port' to the console reader so you could mock it in your unit test.

In addition you should have a **Integration Test** that verifies that your 'adapter' actually works against the real console.

According to the title of your question I guess you want to do an Integration test. You were almost there. You called a deprecated method that is deprecated since Scala 2.11.0. This code should work -

```
"readLine" should "work" in {
  val in = new ByteArrayInputStream("abc".getBytes)
  System.setIn(in)
  StdIn.readLine() === "abc"
}
```